# Doorway transition between hardwood and floating bamboo with different heights

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor

We have hardwood in our whole main level except for a study that had carpet.  I've pulled up the carpet and have been replacing it with floating click bamboo.  I'm trying to figure out what to do with the transition through the doorway to the "traditional" nailed hardwood.  I know that floating bamboo needs to have room for expansion, which means a half inch gap between the wood and any wall or other object and it looks like this is often solved at doorways with a T molding between the two types of flooring.  The challenge I face is that the bamboo is about three eights of an inch lower than the hardwood floor and (from what I understand, which could be wrong), T molding works when both sides of the transition are the same height.  I'd love any guidance, feedback, advice on how to deal with a transition that has slightly different heights.  Thank you!!!

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the transition area?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a threshold molding.

https://www.preverco.com/en/accessories/mouldings